# Representing arbitrary hierarchies in WADL

Tags: web-services, rest, wadl

I am modeling a REST API and part of the API will represent resources that are
organized into an arbitrary hierarchy of nodes with values and sub-nodes (kind
of like a file system or the windows registry).

I would love to create a WADL file so that i can generate the JAX-RS boilerplate
for the API but i'm not sure how to represent such a situation in WADL.

i could just use a string as a template parameter but i'm not sure how i would
detect that that string parameter is allowed to have slashes in its value and
generate the JAX-RS @Path annotation properly.

Is it legit to create a template parameter that is repeatable and expect that
sort of functionality? e.g.

HTTP GET http://my.service.com/registry/path/to/my/node

where the repeated template params are "path", "to", "my", "node" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the current [draft URI template spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-gregorio-uritemplate/) there exists a template that describes what you want:

```
  http://my.service/com/registry{/list*}
```

I have no idea if any WADL tooling actually is capable of parsing all the templates that are defined in the spec yet.  I don't use WADL, and don't recommend it, so I can't help you there.